# Apache 403 Directory index forbidden by Options directive, even with index.html

Tags: apache, centos, http-status-code-403

While attempting to access a certain directory on our server, we get the following 403 error:

```
# /var/log/httpd/error_log
Directory index forbidden by Options directive: <path-to-directory>
```

This is the config file used for the directory (which is included in `httpd.conf`).

```
# /etc/httpd/conf.d/<name-of-app>.conf
<VirtualHost *:80>
  DocumentRoot "<path-to-directory>"
  ServerName <server-name>

 <Directory "<path-to-directory>">
   Options +Indexes
   Order allow,deny
   Allow from all
   Require all granted
 </Directory>

</VirtualHost>
```

The directory in question contains an **index.html** file.

Any help would be **greatly** appreciated.

Comment: Is there any other definition for that directory in the server config? Do you have `NameVirtualHost` enabled?

Comment: Is it turns out, I needed to add DirectoryIndex index.html, and that solved the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this by adding `DirectoryIndex index.html` to the directory.